# Projection of Vector onto Matrix Top Spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection

I'm looking for an efficient way to project a given $n$-dimensional vector $w$ onto specific spectrum part of a given matrix $A$.

Specifically, consider a positive-definite $n \times n$ matrix (actually it is Gramian) $A$ with eigen-decomposition $A = V \cdot \Lambda \cdot V^T$. Each column $v_i$ of $V$ is eigenvector of $A$, with its corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i = \Lambda_{ii}$, where $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3 \geq \ldots$.

Further, all $\{ v_i \}$ represent an orthonormal basis of $n$-dimensional vector space. Due to the last point, $w$ can be written as $w = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot v_i$ where $a_i = <w, v_i>$. I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to compute $\hat{w} = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i \cdot v_i$ where $k << n$. In other words, I want to project $w$ onto the subspace spanned by $k$ top eigenvectors of $A$.

Given $A$ and $w$, I can find $\hat{w}$ by obtaining $A$'s eigendecomposition/SVD. Yet, in my case $n$ is quite large and such decomposition is practically impossible. Is there any other way to compute $\hat{w}$? Any iterative algorithm? Otherwise, can $\hat{w}$ be approximated efficiently up to some epsilon?

More generally, is there a fast way to compute the projection $\sum_{i = k_1}^{k_2} a_i \cdot v_i$ for some $1 \leq k_1  <  k_2 \leq n$?

Any suggestions?

Comment: In matlab, there’s an SVD method that allows you to extract singular vectors corresponding to the k highest/lowest singular values; that should suffice for your purpose

Comment: I assume that by “top” you mean “largest”, but you should say so explicitly in your question

Comment: Yes, I meant the largest eigenvalues, updated the question accordingly

Comment: I know this Matlab's capability. Yet, still it is very expensive for me to perform due to large dimension. I'm looking for some procedure that may compute/estimate $\hat{w}$ with no SVD at all.

Comment: For example, if I perform several matrix-vector products, $\tilde{w} = A^r \cdot w$ typically "moves" towards the top sub-space of $A$ as $r$ increases. I'm looking for some similar procedure to compute $\hat{w}$. Any ideas?

Comment: matlab’s algorithm already exploits this phenomenon so I don’t expect that we’ll be able to do anything significantly faster

Comment: If you really wanted to you could implement your own implementation of a modified QR method, which I suspect would reduce the number of required flops by a constant factor. If you like I could write up a description of that algorithm

Comment: Thanks, no need. I found this algorithm overall description in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm, and I think it would be very hard to obtain a better performance than the available libraries. Thanks again!